# How to remove message `Indentation setup for shell type sh`

Tags: indentation, shell

I open shell files at startup and often get this in `*Messages*`:

```
Setting up indent for shell type sh
Indentation variables are now local.
Indentation setup for shell type sh
```

All my files cause this warning, even if they have indentation, e.g.:

```bash
source /path/to/file.sh

var=0

foo() {
   exit 0 
}
```

When Emacs open Python files, it guesses the indentation from the file and does not produce these messages.

How can I avoid these messages when opening files with shell scripts?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**This is hardcoded** into the function `sh-set-shell` which is called when `sh-mode` is invoked.

**It's probably better to not touch that behaviour** as it will also not display messages if it was not possible to set up indentation correctly.

You can **hide the message in the minibuffer** (will still be displayed in *Messages*) by placing an advice around that function.

```lisp
(advice-add 'sh-set-shell :around
            (lambda (orig-fun &rest args)
              (let ((inhibit-message t))
                (apply orig-fun args))))
```

Or **hide it completely** by lexically overwritting the `message` function:

```lisp
(require cl-lib)
(advice-add 'sh-set-shell :around
            (lambda (orig-fun &rest args)
              (cl-letf (((symbol-function 'message) #'ignore))
                (apply orig-fun args))))
```